# Very strange behaviour with cfhttp an cfhttpparam

Tags: coldfusion, solr, cfhttp, bluedragon

Happy New Year,

The New Year found me wrestling with a coding problem. I am using ColdFusion and as for CFML engine “openBD”. I have a CFC that handles requests for the search engine that I use (SOLR search engine). I am “feeding” that CFC with some arguments. The CFC performs as it should. But when I am trying to pass a specific argument (#apofasi_taxonomy #) the CFC doesn’t returns nothing (If I pass the above argument directly to the search engine –not using CFC- I can see return/search results)

**Part of CFC:**

```
  <cffunction name="searchP" access="remote" returnFormat="json">         
      <cfargument name="q" type="string" default="" required="yes"> 
      <cfargument name="apofasi_taxonomy" type="string" default="apofasi_taxonomy:(*)" required="yes">
      <cfargument name="apofasi_tmima" type="string" default="apofasi_tmima:(*)" required="yes">
      <cfargument name="apofasi_date" type="string" default="apofasi_date:(*)" required="yes">  
      <cfargument name="apofasi_number" type="string" default="apofasi_number:(*)" required="yes"> 
      <!---<cfargument name="apofasi_taxonomy" type="string" default="*">
      <cfargument name="apofasi_tmima" type="string" default="*">
      <cfargument name="apofasi_date" type="string" default="*">  
      <cfargument name="apofasi_number" type="string" default="*">--->

      <cfset theUrl = 'http://localhost/solr/areios_pagos/select/?'>

      <cfhttp method="get" url="#theUrl#" port="8090" result="rs" username="abcd" password="********">
        <cfhttpparam type="url" name="q" value="#q#">
        <cfhttpparam type="url" name="fq" value="#apofasi_taxonomy#+#apofasi_tmima#+#apofasi_date#+#apofasi_number#">
        <!---<cfhttpparam type="url" name="fq" value="apofasi_taxonomy:(3068 || ΠΟΙΝΙΚΕΣ) AND apofasi_date:(2010)">--->        
        <!---<cfhttpparam type="url" name="fq" value="apofasi_taxonomy:(3068) AND apofasi_date:(*) AND apofasi_number:(*)">--->
        <cfhttpparam type="url" name="rows" value="120">
        <cfhttpparam type="url" name="wt" value="json">
        <cfhttpparam type="url" name="sort" value="score desc">
        <cfhttpparam type="url" name="hl" value="true">
        <cfhttpparam type="url" name="hl.fl" value="content,title">
        <cfhttpparam type="url" name="fl" value="grid_title,title,url,ida,model,search_tag,solr_id">
        <cfhttpparam type="url" name="f.content.hl.alternateField" value="content">
        <cfhttpparam type="url" name="hl.maxAlternateFieldLength" value="800">
      </cfhttp>
```

**Notice that the search engine consumes urls like:**

```
http://localhost/solr/areios_pagos/select/?q=blahblah&fq=apofasi_taxonomy:(3068)+ apofasi_tmima:(Α || Ζ)+ apofasi_date:(2007 || 2012)+apofasi_number:(666)
```

What I have checked until now: The arguments that I am passing to CFC are 100% OK (from html), I have double-checked if the search engine can consume the above url syntax. But I have noticed a very strange behavior. When I exclude the **#apofasi_taxonomy#** or **#apofasi_tmima#** arguments from the url completely the CFC is working (it returns results). 
The values that **#apofasi_taxonomy#** argument takes are: `apofasi_taxonomy:(ΠΟΙΝΙΚΕΣ)`, `apofasi_taxonomy:(ΠΟΛΙΤΙΚΕΣ)`, `apofasi_taxonomy:(3068)` or `apofasi_taxonomy:(ΠΟΙΝΙΚΕΣ || 3068)`, `apofasi_taxonomy:(ΠΟΙΝΙΚΕΣ || ΠΟΛΙΤΙΚΕΣ)` and so on.

I have noticed one more thing, **#apofasi_taxonomy#** argument is working with the values below: `apofasi_taxonomy(ΠΟΙΝΙΚΕΣ)`, `apofasi_taxonomy:(ΠΟΛΙΤΙΚΕΣ)`and `apofasi_taxonomy:(ΠΟΛΙΤΙΚΕΣ || ΠΟΙΝΙΚΕΣ)` but it is not working for `apofasi_taxonomy:(3068)`, `apofasi_taxonomy:(ΠΟΛΙΤΙΚΕΣ || 3068)`, `apofasi_taxonomy:(ΠΟΛΙΤΙΚΕΣ || 3068)` or `apofasi_taxonomy:(ΠΟΛΙΤΙΚΕΣ || ΠΟΛΙΤΙΚΕΣ || 3068)`. Isn’t that weird?

The values that **#apofasi_tmima#** argument takes are: `Α || Α1 || Α2 || Β || Β2 || Γ || Δ || Ε || ΣΤ || Ζ || ΟΛΟΜΕΛΕΙΑ` e.g. `apofasi_tmima(Β || Β2 || ΟΛΟΜΕΛΕΙΑ)`.

Keep in mind that the above values are in Greek language.

Is there anyone out there that can help?

With respect,
Tom

**edit: Moved requested XML provided in comments to the question**

```
<fieldType name="text_areios_pagos" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="lang/stopwords_en.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/> 
        <filter class="solr.EnglishPossessiveFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="lang/stopwords_el.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true"/>
        <filter class="solr.GreekLowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.GreekStemFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
        <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="lang/stopwords_en.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="lang/stopwords_el.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true"/>
        <filter class="solr.GreekLowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.GreekStemFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.EnglishPossessiveFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/> 
        <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Comment: does it work if you search without special characters?

Comment: Nothing to do with your problem but I noticed that your cfargument tags have required="yes" and default values.  Doesn't one defeat the purpose of the other?

Comment: @Dan Bracuk I have removed "default" and "required" directive but it doesn't work!

Comment: @Matt Busche What kind of special characters do you mean?

Comment: @anarchos78 the non English characters like `ΠΟΛΙΤΙΚΕΣ`

Comment: @Matt Busche With "ΠΟΛΙΤΙΚΕΣ" or "ΠΟΙΝΙΚΕΣ" is working! Its not working with "3068"

Comment: How is the `apofasi_taxonomy` field defined in the Solr schema.xml? Please add the `<fields>` entry for this field as well as the corresponding `<fieldType>` as defined by the `type` property to your question. It could be that field definition is not indexing/querying numbers properly.

Comment: @Paige Cook The `<field>` definition: `<field  name="apofasi_taxonomy" type="text_areios_pagos" indexed="true" stored="true"/>`. The `<fieldType>`:`<fieldType name="text_areios_pagos" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">`

Comment: Thanks, but that is not the entire fieldType definition, can you include everything between the `<fieldType ...>` and `</fieldType>` entries.

Comment: @Paige Cook You will see three(3) part. Please throw it to a XML beautifier

Comment: @Paige Cook <fieldType name="text_areios_pagos" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100"><analyzer type="index"><tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/><filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="lang/stopwords_en.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true"/><filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
     <filter class="solr.EnglishPossessiveFilterFactory"/><filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="lang/stopwords_el.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true"/><filter class="solr.GreekLowerCaseFilterFactory"/>

Comment: @Paige Cook<filter class="solr.GreekStemFilterFactory"/><filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/><filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/></analyzer><analyzer type="query"><tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/><filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/><filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="lang/stopwords_en.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true"/><filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="lang/stopwords_el.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true"/>

Comment: @Paige Cook<filter class="solr.GreekLowerCaseFilterFactory"/><filter class="solr.GreekStemFilterFactory"/><filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/><filter class="solr.EnglishPossessiveFilterFactory"/><filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
        <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/></analyzer></fieldType>

Comment: @Paige Cook It has nothing to do with solr. As i already told if i query solr like: `http://localhost/solr/areios_pagos/select/?q=blahblah&fq=apofasi_taxonomy:(3068)+apofasi_tmima:(Α || Ζ)+apofasi_date:(2007 || 2012)+apofasi_number:(666)` it is working the problem is on ColdFusion side

Comment: Thanks @Travis for adding the xml to the question, much easier to read:) Sorry, it was not clear from your question that the Solr side is working properly.

Comment: @anarchos78 have you attempted to output `#apofasi_taxonomy#+#apofasi_tmima#+#apofasi_date#+#apofasi_number#` to see if it is exactly as you expect it? that is, does it = `apofasi_taxonomy:(3068‌​)+apofasi_tmima:(Α || Ζ)+apofasi_date:(2007 || 2012)+apofasi_number:(666)` as you searched for it in solr?

Comment: @Travis I haven't tested that. Is ther a way to see what is the `cfhttp` object is formed? I don't know how to do it.

Comment: try `<cfoutput>#apofasi_taxonomy#+#apofasi_tmima#+#apofasi_date#+#apofasi_number#</cfoutput><cfabort>` just before your cfhttp tag if that doesn't work use `<cfreturn #apofasi_taxonomy#+#apofasi_tmima#+#apofasi_date#+#apofasi_number#>` just before the cfhttp tag

Comment: sorry `<cfreturn "#apofasi_taxonomy#+#apofasi_tmima#+#apofasi_date#+#apofasi_number#">`

Comment: @Travis it is outputting well. I will try to re-check solr side. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may have to add a charset attribute to your cfhttp tag

```
    <cfhttp ... charset="ISO-8859-7" ...
```